# Common Lisp: Trouble with * in function type-specifier

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Since a few weeks, I realize that I have troubles with a specific construct regarding type specifiers.
First of all, I am using SBCL 2.1.9, compiled from source, which "apparently passes all the tests".

Here is the problem: when I try to specify a type for a function using this form

```
(declaim (ftype (function (*) int) foo))
```

here is what SBCL tells me

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001870303}>:
  * is not permitted as an argument to the FUNCTION type specifier
```

It could very well be completely normal if not for a few reasons:

- When using the exact same form on another machine with SBCL 2.1.8, this form is perfectly valid
- The spec does not seem to forbid such a construct, although it is very hard to tell. For example, there is a bunch of code in the sb-kernel, namely the `types.lisp` file (entirely written in the `SB-KERNEL` package), which is dedicated to catch invalid * symbols in type specifiers. Without reading in details those functions, it is hard to tell whether this is normal or not.
- Many people, with much, much experience than I have, use this construct in their projects. It has caused me a lot of trouble when trying to compile them by hand recently, as SBCL would not let me compile those forms. For example, I opened an issue for the Nyxt browser regarding this very problem, and I still have trouble compiling the game engine cl-bodge which has been successfully used to make quite a large number of games (and so, such bugs should have been long gone by now)

And so, I have a few questions:

- Once and for all, is the problematic form valid Common Lisp or not ?
- If it is not, why do so many people, including some of the most knowledgeable persons about CL, use it (seemingly without any problem) ?
- If it is (and I am pretty sure it is), is there any reason why I observe this behaviour, even after recompiling SBCL and passing all the tests ?
- Do you have any idea on how I could fix this, so I no longer have to manually rewrite all the ftype declarations of this form as `(ftype (function (t) bar)` foo) in all the libraries that I try to compile ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You could try a Comby rule/script to rewrite the declarations automatically: https://comby.dev/ It's better than a regexp since it handles parenthesis and comments for us. (& the guys at Nyxt are quite new to CL type declarations ;) (worked with them))

Answer (score 5):

`(function (*) ...)` has never been legal CL: see [the hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fn.htm).  SBCL may have accepted it although I don't know what it would have meant (perhaps the same as `(function (&rest t) ...)`?).  If 'some of the most knowledgeable persons about CL' have been using then, well, I won't speculate on their knowledge about CL, but I'd strongly suggest they either fix their declarations or conditionalise them based on implementations that will accept them.